# How to reduce this archive detection function and make it supports wildcards

Tags: c#, regex

The function below is called to determine if a given file is the archive of another file. I'm also looking for a way to supports wildcards. For example if the original log file is serverw3c.log and we type serverw3c*.log, it returns true for the following:

- serverw3c.log.2011-02-04
- serverw3c.log
- serverw3c.log.20110204_120132
- serverw3c_20110204.log

The code:

```
/// <summary>
/// Check if a given file is an archive of an original file.
/// The check is performed on the names of the files only.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="originalFile">The original file.</param>
/// <param name="archivedFile">The file which is supposed to be an archive of the original one.</param>
/// <returns>True if the file is an archive, False otherwise.</returns>
public bool IsArchive(string originalFile, string archivedFile)
{
    // We assume that an archived file has the name of the original 
    // concatenated with a timestamp '.YYYYMMDD_HHMMSS'
    Regex exp = new Regex(string.Concat(originalFile, ".", "[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-1][0-9][0-9][0-9]_[0-2][0-9][0-5][0-9][0-5][0-9]"));
    if (exp.IsMatch(archivedFile))
        return true;

    exp = new Regex(string.Concat(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(originalFile), "_", "[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]", Path.GetExtension(".log")));
    if (exp.IsMatch(archivedFile))
        return true;

    exp = new Regex(string.Concat(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(originalFile), "_", "[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]", "_", "[0-9][0-9][0-9]", Path.GetExtension(".log")));
    if (exp.IsMatch(archivedFile))
        return true;

    exp = new Regex(string.Concat(originalFile, ".", "[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]"));
    if (exp.IsMatch(archivedFile))
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't make the code formatting to work properly.

Comment: Do you need those wildcards to be those date formats, or could they be anything, e.g. `serverw3BACKUP.log`?

Comment: Anything, this could replace the function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your regex can be shortened using `{x}`, which repeat a pattern `x` times. So your third regex would become:

```
exp = new Regex(string.Concat(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(originalFile),
                              "_[0-9]{8}_[0-9]{3}",
                              Path.GetExtension(".log")));
```

As far as wildcards, if you use `*` it will be entered into the regex. It looks from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.aspx) that it won't be removed from the file name when you call `GetFileNameWithoutExtension()`. However, I was unable to test this as I don't have Visual Studio on my computer. It worked as a wildcard on my regex tests.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the wildcard alternative

```
public bool IsArchive(string filePattern, string archivedFile)
{
    return new Regex(filePattern.Replace("*", "[^ ]*")).IsMatch(archivedFile);
}
```